# Add New Chosen(chosen-ajax-addition) dynamically and Search dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to add new chosen but I can't search dynamically.

```
    $('.chosen_urun').ajaxChosen({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url:'ajax/stok_arama.php'
    },{
        loadingImg: 'assets/img/loading.gif'
    });
```

I am using this code. It search first element  then I add new  dynamically and I want to dynamically search like first element. How can I do that?

Comment: What element are you talking about? What do you want to search for?

Comment: I solved my problem. I am using https://github.com/ksykulev/chosen-ajax-addition .Sorry for alittle information about my question. Why I ask like that. Thanks